# ng-options not pulling from javascript array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="department" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Department</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <select name="department" id="department" class="form-control"
                              ng-model="employee.department"
                        ng-options="dept for dept in departments"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <br />
```

```
angularFormsApp.controller('efController',
function efController($scope, efService) {

    $scope.employee = efService.employee;

    $scope.departments = [
        "Engineering",
        "Marketing",
        "Finance",
        "Administration"
    ];

});
```

Comment: Please be more specific when detailing a problem . Take a few minutes to read [ask]

Comment: Note that the ng-options shown works just fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/STLY1vVuZykiXgZbDiTO?p=preview

Comment: It is working fine for us , here is the woking html code : '<select  
                              ng-model="employee.department"
                        ng-options="dept for dept in departments"></select>'

Please look over the css class or styles that added on your Id and class .